# Getting error attempting to Iterate over a JCoTable using java.util.iterator

Tags: java, sapjco3

Am trying to implement some Java patterns (Facade, and Iterator) against JCo objects.

Here, I'm trying to create an Iterator over the `JCoTable` much like I would any collection in Java.  Below is my class snippet. In `MyClass` I have an inner class that performs the iteration.

I'm using the `table.getStructure(...)` methods, but am missing something.  I've seen some snippets where they're explicitly creating a structure using metadata, but honestly, the code is not present in those examples, and I struggle a little there, worrying that I'm trading one complexity for another.

My goal is to simplify SAP BAPI calls and table handling for other Java programmers.  This is a refactoring exercise.  My return variables are incompatible in the Iterator.

Thank you in advance.

My class:

```
class MyClass 
...
protected JCoTable table;
...

private class JCoTableIterator implements Iterator<JCoRecord> {

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return table.getRow() < table.getNumRows();
    }
    @Override
    public JCoRecord next() {
        return table.getStructure(table.getRow() + 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        table.deleteRow();
    }
}
```

My implementation:

```
Iterator<JCoRecord> it = table.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    JCoRecord record = it.next(); <<<<< *Exception
    logger.info(record.getString("WERKS"));
    ... other field procesing ... 
}
```

But on the `JCoRecord record = it.next()` line I get the following error.

> ```
> com.sap.conn.jco.ConversionException: (122) JCO_ERROR_CONVERSION: Cannot convert 
>                                 field VBELN of type CHAR to StructureRecord
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.AbstractRecord.createConversionException(AbstractRecord.java:415)
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.AbstractRecord.createConversionException(AbstractRecord.java:410)
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.AbstractRecord.getStructure(AbstractRecord.java:2472)
> ```

Comment: Could you please specify exactly which version of the JCo you're using? There are huge API differences between version 2 and 3, maybe that's why you're confused by various examples that don't work.

Comment: @vwegert, I'm using JCo 3.  I presume that because I use the sapjco3.dll and sapjco3.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to iterate over the rows of the table, I'd say you're using `JCoTable.getStructure()` out of place. As the name suggests, it takes the nth field of the  record that is currently selected and attempts to return it as a structure. This is of course only possible if that individual column is a structured column - if it is a single (atomic) field, then I'd expect this conversion to fail with exactly the error message you're encountering.

Comment: I realized after further looking at the API, that I really didn't need to write my own Iterator... The methods off JCoTable are sufficient with .nextRow(), .firstRow(), etc....

Comment: To be honest, I was wondering why you tried to reinvent the wheel in the first place... ;-)

Comment: Sometimes things don't click with me right away--old age, I think.  I'm the primary/sole developer here with a couple others who are new to Java but eager.  So, I was trying to simplify the interfaces somewhat.  We are a new SAP shop (1 year).  I'm still learning the RFC/JCo stuff myself.  I appreciate the suppressed laughter!  :)